# Electron - Use require in local Windows network

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building an Electron application. It uses jquery to do some things.
I insert jquery with this in my index page:

```
<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
</script>
```

And jquery is stored in `/node_modules/jquery.js`.
This works fine when i run the app local or on an network drive. But if i run it on the local network it can't find the module jquery.

So:
`X:\app\Electron.exe` can load jquery, while 
`\\servername\share\app\Electron.exe`can't.

I've to use a relative path, because the app can be runned from different locations.

I did try to use other relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution! But I do have a workaround.
I compressed the hole project with WinRar:

---

Select all files -> Add to archive
Archive name -> Name of your Electron application.
Archiving options -> Create SFX archive
Now go to "Advanced" tab -> SFX Options
Run after extraction -> electron.exe (or if you renamed it, that name)
Go to "Modes" tab  -> Unpack to temporary folder
Silent mode -> Hide all
Ok -> Ok

---

Now you get one .exe file. What happens if you run it from any place:

1. The SFX archive extracts itself in a temporary location (appdata).
2. After extraction the app will be executed.

So you never get the problem, because it's local.

But i think it will cost some performance...?

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file with:

```
pushd \\server\share\
your-electron-program.exe
popd
```

This will dynamically create a mapped drive and get rid of it once the program ends.

If you don't like having a `.bat` file and the command window, buy [Batch Compiler](http://bc.gotek.info/) and compile it into an Exe. Or other similar program.